add JSON object keys and values to bash associative array
I want to loop through a JSON object and add the keys and values to a Bash associative array.
Here's my JSON object that is in a file named deploy.json.
"deploymentEnvs": {
  "dev": "zone_dev",
  "test": "zone_test",
  "prod": "zone_prod"
}

I want to take the keys and values and add them to a Bash associative array, something like this:
declare -A deployenvs
deployenvs[dev]="zone_dev"
deployenvs[test]="zone_test"
deployenvs[prod]="zone_prod"

So far I have this command jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.deploymentEnvs' deploy.json. When I run it I get a jq error stating `Cannot index array with string "deploymentEnvs". I couldn't find a StackOverflow post that specifically applied to my situation. I figured I need to do some kind of while loop using the above jq command but I'm stuck on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

A JSON array is not a Bash array. Construct the Bash array using declare, and have jq print the declaration the way Bash requires it.

using the traditional [key]=value format

declare -A deployenvs="($(
  jq -r '.deploymentEnvs | to_entries[] | @sh "[\(.key)]=\(.value)"' deploy.json
))"


or using the newer key value format:

declare -A deployenvs="($(
  jq -r '.deploymentEnvs | to_entries[] | .key, .value | @sh' deploy.json
))"

Both will generate an associative array in Bash:
declare -p deployenvs

declare -A deployenvs=([prod]="zone_prod" [dev]="zone_dev" [test]="zone_test" )


it seems to work but I do not understand why. could you explain the quotes in declare -A deployenvs="($( ... ))"?
Also, note that the declare makes it impossible to check if jq managed deploy.json successfully

@user24246119 Then do it in two separate steps. First, capture the output of jq into a Bash variable (and perform your necessary checks), e.g. decl="$(jq -r '…' deploy.json)" || exit 1. Here, "$(…)" captures the outputs of the inner command as a single string. Then, use that variable to declare the associative array, e.g. declare -A deployenvs="($decl)" (or declare -A "deployenvs=($decl)" or declare -A deployenvs=("$decl")). Here, the parens are part of the array declaration, and the quotes ensure once again that whitespace segmentation does not occur.
